# How to edit SOAP requst body

Tags: c#, .net, soap, wsdl

I added a web service using Visual Studio and wrote the following code:

```
ReceiverClient rc = new ReceiverClient();
            
            
var task = rc.sendDocumentAsync("arg1", "arg2", "arg3");
            
            
var resutl = task.Result;
```

So it creates the request:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
  <s:Header>
    <a:Action>sendDocument</a:Action>
    <transportHeader xmlns="http://example.com" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <authInfo>
        <clientEntityId>clientId</clientEntityId>
      </authInfo>
    </transportHeader>
    <a:MessageID>messageId</a:MessageID>
    <a:ReplyTo>
      <a:Address>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</a:Address>
    </a:ReplyTo>
    <a:To></a:To>
    <wsse:Security>
    </wsse:Security>
  </s:Header>
  <s:Body xmlns:d2p1="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/02/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" d2p1:Id="BodyID-6b6c35aa-a174-4b47-a1bf-bafa61efed78">
    <sendDocument xmlns="http://example.com">
      <oid xmlns="">oid</oid>
      <service xmlns="">service</service>
      <document xmlns="">document</document>
    </sendDocument>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

I need to replace *clientId* by the real id, is there a way to edit the request body somehow ?

Answer (score -1):

Using Xml Linq :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication193
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string xml = File.ReadAllText(FILENAME);
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

            XElement id = doc.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "clientEntityId").FirstOrDefault();
            id.SetValue("123");
  
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Yeah, but this xml file is not stored in my computer :(

Comment: XDocument can use a URI instead of a filename